# Custom order number or increment id in Magento

Tags: magento-1.7, orders, increment-id

I want to shorten order number (increment id) but I don't want to use any modules.

Comment: See http://newsinfo-blog.blogspot.com/2016/05/set-custom-order-increment-id-in-magento.html

Comment: In case you are interested https://magecomp.com/magento-custom-order-number.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To reduce the number of digits, you'll want to modify the `increment_pad_length` in the `eav_entity_type` table (for the `order` row, of course).

You can change the prefix by modifying the `increment_prefix` value in the `eav_entity_store` table.  (Use the `entity_type_id` from the other table to identify which row you'd change.) By default, Magento uses the store's id (`1`) as the prefix.

If you're interested in learning more about the increment IDs, check out the `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Increment_Numeric` and `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Increment_Abstract` classes which are responsible for generating the next available ID based on the database settings.

**Edit:** You could even create your own increment logic by extending the Abstract class I mentioned above.

Answer (score 3):

I dont´t know a module for this, but you can "easily" tweak the table **eav_entity_store**. You can look up the entity_id in **eav_entity_type**