# Importing orders and order numbers magento 2.1

Tags: magento-2.1, magento-2.1.1

I am trying to migrate another shopping cart to magento 2.1

The other shopping cart has been in use for quite a while and has lots of orders.

I have managed to import products, categories  and now making the skin

I can sort of import orders - in that I can get the order content, the date the order was made, billing and shipping address etc. Payment method is of no consequence. And shipping method flat rate is fine for historical orders. But at the time of transition we might have to keep two systems alive for a couple of months.

BUT - my big problem is order numbers - historical order numbers. 
All the imported orders start from 10M and it does not listen to the order number increment. My old orders start from 4XXX and go to 30XXX. If a customer calls and refers to their old order for warranty purposes, I do not have an easy way to find it.

Is there a way to add another attribute to an order - like old_order_number  and import the old order number into that variable?
Is it possible to make magento 2.1 just accept the old order number for historical orders, and keep that trend going for newer orders?

I know this is a uncommon case that people are moving to magento form another shopping cart - but it would increase footprint for magento if they made this easy, and it would also make the whole process easier.

Please offer suggestions and accept my thanks in advance for the same
Sam

Answer (score 0):

To clarify, you are trying to get order increments to follow the same pattern of your previous platform?

Magento's standard formatting is 100000001....100000002....etc.

Am I correct in saying that your old platform order IDs are 4001...4002.../...30001...30002?

If this is the case, you can check this previous post on shortening the order ID.

[Custom order number or increment id in Magento](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/31991/custom-order-number-or-increment-id-in-magento)